# Authorization for a POST request to Google Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out how to use Google Cloud Storage for my app. The app should allow any user to POST (or PUT) objects into a Bucket and also let them read any files from said bucket. I am confused as to how I am supposed to form my POST requests in order to make this work.

I have just been playing around, sending requests to see if I can upload a file into a bucket. I have tried forming a request according to this example: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

```
POST /upload/storage/v1/b/<bucketname>/o?uploadType=media&name=<objectname> HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 100
Authorization: Bearer <your_auth_token>
```

I am confused as to what exactly the 'auth_token' is. I have tried going into the developers console and generating a 'Public API access' key and attempted to use this, but I got a response saying it was unauthorized.

Am I generating the right type of key? I understand OAuth keys are used when you need access to a Google user's data. I don't need this: I simply need to allow users of my app to add files to a bucket and read from that bucket. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is like an ID to identify you have permission to perform your actions, as you haven´t provide which language you are using, I will provide a golang example

https://github.com/johnbalvin/google-cloud-go/blob/master/storage/resumableUpload.go